# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{{\tan x-\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left( \tan x\right)\right)}}{\tan x+\cos^2(\tan x)}}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{{\tan x-\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left( \tan x\right)\right)}}{\tan x+\cos^2(\tan x)}} = \_\_\_$$

My approach is as follow

Let $\tan x = T$

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{T \to \infty } \sqrt {\frac{{T - \sin \left( {{{\tan }^{ - 1}}T} \right)}}{{T + {{\cos }^2}T}}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{T \to \infty } \sqrt {\frac{{1 - \frac{{\sin \left( {{{\tan }^{ - 1}}T} \right)}}{T}}}{{1 + \frac{{{{\cos }^2}T}}{T}}}}  = 1$$

Though answer is correct but want to confirm whether the method is OK

Comment: Unfortunately the change of variables is wrong. $\lim \tan x$ as $x \rightarrow \pi/2$ does not exist- from the left $tan x$ goes to $\infty$ but from the right $\tan x$ goes to $-\infty$. So your limit after change of variables doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A change of variables on $y=f(x)$ on a limit where $x\to x_0$ is not the wisest choice when $x_0$ is a pole of $f$, as is the case here, since different directions lead to different limiting values, as poined out in comments.

Instead, note that although $\tan x$ diverges as $x\to\pi/2$ from whatever direction is chosen, $\sin\tan^{-1}\tan x=\sin x$ and $\cos^2\tan x$ are bounded in $[-1,1]$, even though the latter oscillates with infinitely increasing frequency. As such we can ignore the two "bags on the side" and get that the limit equals
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{\tan x}{\tan x}}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

> $$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{{\tan x-\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left( \tan x\right)\right)}}{\tan x+\cos^2(\tan x)}} = \_\_\_$$

Personally, with this type of problem, I advocate dispensing with any attempt at elegance.  The $\tan^{-1}$ function (i.e. the ArcTan function) has as its range

$-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2.$

So, as $x$ approaches (but does not equal) $\pi/2$ what is the ArcTan$(t)$, where $t = \tan(x)$?  If $x$ is approaching $(\pi/2)$ **from above**, then $t$ is negative, so ArcTan$(t)$ must be approaching $-\pi/2$ from **above**.

Alternatively, as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ from below, then
$t$ is positive, so ArcTan$(t) = x.$  So, dispensing with any attempt at elegance, you have to evaluate the left side limit (i.e. as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ from below) separately from the right side limit.

Then, you have to verify that

- both limits exist (i.e. are finite)
- the two limits equal each other.

If both bullet points above are satisfied then the overall expression has a single limit.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1}~: x ~\text{is approaching} ~(\pi/2)~\text{from below}}$

With $t = \tan(x)$, in Case 1, you have that ArcTan$(t) = x$.  So, the expression to be evaluated can be expressed in terms of $t$.  As $x$ approaches $(\pi/2)$ from below, $t$ approaches $+\infty$.  Then,

- $\tan(x) = t.$
- $\sin(x) = \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}}.$
- $\cos^2[\tan(x)] = \cos^2(t),$ 
  which will oscillate between $0$ and $+1$, as $t \to \infty$.

Denoting $\cos^2(t)$ as $\delta$, with $0 \leq \delta \leq 1,$ then in Case 1, the expression to be evaluated is

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{t - \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}}}{t + \delta}}. \tag1 $$

Since

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}} = 1,$$

the expression in (1) above evaluates to

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{t - 1}{t + \delta}} = 1,$$

because $\delta$ is bounded.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2}~: x ~\text{is approaching} ~(\pi/2)~\text{from above}}$

With $t = \tan(x)$, in Case 2, you have that ArcTan$(t) = [x - \pi]$.  Again, the expression to be evaluated can be expressed in terms of $t$, as long as you are careful.

As $x$ approaches $(\pi/2)$ from above, $[x - \pi]$ approaches $-\pi/2$ from above.  Here, 
$t = \tan(x) = \tan(x - \pi)$ approaches $-\infty$.  Then,

- $\tan(x) = \tan(x - \pi) = t.$
- $\sin(x - \pi) = \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}} < 0.$
- $\cos^2[\tan(x)] = \cos^2(t),$ 
  which will oscillate between $0$ and $+1$, as $t \to -\infty$.

Denoting $\cos^2(t)$ as $\delta$, with $0 \leq \delta \leq 1,$ then in Case 2, the expression to be evaluated is

$$\lim_{t \to -\infty} \sqrt{\frac{t - \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}}}{t + \delta}}. \tag2 $$

Since

$$\lim_{t\to -\infty} \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}} = -1,$$

the expression in (2) above evaluates to

$$\lim_{t \to -\infty}\sqrt{\frac{t + 1}{t + \delta}} = 1,$$

because $\delta$ is bounded.

---

So, in Case 1 and Case 2, the limit evaluates to $1$.  This implies that the left side limit and right side limit are both finite and are equal to each other.  Therefore, the overall limit is equal to $(1).$